# Permissions issues during make

Tags: macos, makefile, macos-catalina

I'm currently trying to build arpack on my mac. I've built the component libraries but for some reason now I am getting this error

```
/Users/username/packages/arPACK/libarpack.a
make[1]: /Users/username/packages/arPACK/libarpack.a: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [single] Error 1
```

I'm not sure why the permissions are set this way. I've tried sudo but still the same issue persists.

Comment: Hmm, why is it printing `$HOME` like that?  Also `/Users/$HOME` is not the same as `/Users/username` (it would expand to `/Users/Users/username`) so it's probably whatever is setting that path.

Comment: repair permissions...   also what $HOME ?? must have been edited out of the question??

Comment: $HOME was replaced with username -- I wasn't used to the formatting on the site